# Regex Lookaround with only one match where multiple possible matches available

Tags: regex

Got this:

```
<TAG>something one</TAG><TAG>something two</TAG><TAG>something three</TAG>
```

I want only match: `something two`
I try: `(?<=<TAG>)(.*two.*)(?=<\/TAG>)`
but got:

```
something one</TAG><TAG>something two</TAG><TAG>something three
```

Maybe I give another example

```
RECORDsomething beetwenRECORD RECORDanything beetwenRECORD etc.
```

want to get words beetwen RECORD

Comment: You shall not try to match HTML with regular expressions. What host language are you using?

Comment: What are you trying to do? A DOM crawler seems better suited for what you're trying to do. Please tell me you're not running this over an element's `innerHTML`?

Comment: Its not HTML for me. The mayor problem is that: if there are many elements which are the same, like <TAG> or something else, the expression gets the first one. I want <TAG> which is first next to "something two".

Comment: Then maybe it is XML. Still not a job for regex. And you did not say what your host language is.

Comment: Its java. For android purpose.

Comment: There is a nice XML parser for Android. Look into the `DocumentBuilderFactory`, `DocumentBuilderFactory` and `Document` classes. One of many examples how to use them is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5445608/18771

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<TAG>.+?<TAG>(.*?)</TAG>
```

Your `something two` is in the first match in `$1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=</TAG><TAG>)[^<]*(?=</TAG><TAG>)
```

Comment: Encouraging people to parse HTML with regular expressions is counter productive. Also this solution does not address the *actual* issue the OP has with his regex.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, parsing HTML using regular expressions is discouraged! There are plenty of HTML parsers for doing this. But if you want a regex at all costs, here is how I would it in Python:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = '<TAG>something one</TAG><TAG>something two</TAG><TAG>something three</TAG>'

In [3]: re.findall(r'(?<=<TAG>).*?(?=</TAG>)', s)[1]
Out[3]: 'something two'
```

However, this solution only works if you always want to extract the content of the second tag pair. But as I said, don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the TAG is not the first and not the last, you can do

```
(?<=.+<TAG>)(.*two.*)(?=<\/TAG>.+)
```

Of course, it's much better to capture the tags as well and use a capturing group

```
.*<TAG>(.*two.*?)<\/TAG>
```