# Segmentation Fault when using DocumentBuilderFactory through the Java Bridge in Delphi

Tags: java, delphi, java-native-interface, delphi-xe5

I'm trying to use javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory in Delphi code through the JNI/Java Bridge.

This is the interface I constructed for the factory:

> Note: I know in the class the actual creation method is newInstance()
>   but when I try using newInstance instead of init I also get the same
>   segmentation fault.

```
{DocumentBuilderFactory}
JDocumentBuilderFactoryClass = interface(JObjectClass)
['{8475A5A9-F10A-4DDA-9D50-C714C015C81C}']
    function init: JDocumentBuilderFactory; cdecl; overload;
end;

[JavaSignature('javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory')]
JDocumentBuilderFactory = interface(JObject)
['{7F4F2927-25EB-4B03-9373-A43B0757CD06}']
    function newDocumentBuilder: JDocumentBuilder; cdecl;
end;

TJDocumentBuilderFactory = class
     (TJavaGenericImport<JDocumentBuilderFactoryClass, JDocumentBuilderFactory>)
end;
```

And this is the code calling the interface/object:

`tmpObject: JObject;`

```
// init an object, i have already tried just calling create
tmpObject := TJDocumentBuilderFactory.JavaClass.init;
//then wrap it into the appropriate object
if Assigned(tmpObject) then
    builderFactory := TJDocumentBuilderFactory.Wrap
        ((tmpObject as IlocalObject).GetObjectID);
```

As far as I know I don't have to declare every method of the java class in the interface, I have used other classes without problems.

Usually segmentation faults raised by the java bridge indicate that there is a problem loading the interface or file. For example, if the path to the java class in the java signature is wrong then that will result in a segmentation fault too. However this is not the case here since I can confirm that the path is right. I've looked around but I can't find any suggestions as to how to resolve this problem. Any ideas?

regards,
Jason

Comment: I'm not sure. How would check that?
I wanted to do something along the lines of:
`builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();`
`document = builder.parse("input.xml");` 
after creating the builderFactory.
See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445608/android-xml-parser-or-library-for-simple-xml-node-strings/5445824#5445824)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segmentation fault is understandable because it is not possible to create instances of abstract classes.

The Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) says that DocumentBuilderFactory is an abstract class. The class provides a static method, [newDocumentBuilder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newDocumentBuilder%28%29), which returns a new instance of a DocumentBuilder.

To create an instance of the factory, use DocumentBuilderFactory.[newInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance())().

---

As I do not work with a mobile edition of Delphi, I can not say how a static factory method can be used over the JNI adapter. If it is not documented, maybe it is worth its own Stackoverflow question.

Comment: I suspected that it was related to the fact that the class was abstract. I know static methods can be accessed by placing the new DocumentBuilder method in the JDocumentBuilderFactoryClass interface, and then calling it the same way the newInstance method would be called. When I tried that it also resulted in a segmentation fault though. The source of BuilderFactory shows that the newDocuemntBuilder method is also abstract. would that be the cause of this seg fault?

Comment: Please see the Note in my original question. I've tried using newInstance originally, but I also tried it again with the same results. Do I need to use newInstance(factoryClassName, classLoader)?

Comment: @ThePenguin see my edit - I would expect this to be covered in the JNI bridge docs/FAQ